# SQL Count data from 08:00:00 AM to 07:59:59 AM (The next day).I want generate date wise report for a month.

Tags: datetime, select, join, casting, sql-server-2008-r2

The problem is I am not getting proper match of count. It will change when 1st date of month and last date of month
Below is my Table Schema.

COLUMN_NAME     IS_NULLABLE    DATA_TYPE
ID              NO              int
VEHICLE_ID      YES             nvarchar
TYPE            YES             nvarchar
CLASS           YES             nvarchar
TYPE_ID         YES             int
CLASS_ID        YES             int
LANE_ID         YES             nvarchar
TOLL_ID         YES             nvarchar
PASS_NO         YES             nvarchar
DATE            YES             date
TIME            YES             time
LAST_MODIFIED   YES             datetime

My Query:

select COUNT(*),Vm.Date  from VEHICLE_MASTER VM where
CAST(Vm.DATE AS DATETIME) + VM.Time BETWEEN '2017-09-01 08:00:00' AND '2017-09-30 07:59:00'
And Toll_Id='125002'
Group By Vm.Date

I want result in below Bold format

**Sr No Date    Count** Count Description
**1 01-09-2017  66703** 01-09-2017 08:00:00 To 02-09-2017 07:59:59 
**2 02-09-2017  55009** 02-09-2017 08:00:00 To 03-09-2017 07:59:59
**3 29-09-2017  32345** 29-09-2017 08:00:00 To 30-09-2017 07:59:59
**4 30-09-2017  67876** 30-09-2017 08:00:00 To 01-10-2017 07:59:59

please help me out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the type of `Vm.DATE`?

Comment: Please post the **table structure** and any indexes you have defined on this table. Also: what are *33cr* rows?? Please use **globally understandable** measurements - thousands, millions, billions ....

Comment: vm.date date and vm.time time(7)

Comment: 330 Millions rows, Yes, I using non-cluster index on Date, Toll_Id

Comment: You need to define better indices / revise how you store time, but with that current index you will probably get better results with `where Vm.DATE >= cast(@START_DATE as date) and Vm.DATE < cast(@END_DATE + 1 as date) and CAST(Vm.DATE AS DATETIME) + vm.Time BETWEEN @START_DATE AND @END_DATE and vm.TOLL_ID = '102001'`.

Comment: Thank you GSerg, This condition is also fine, but not increase execution performance of query. I want to increase execution performance....

Comment: Have you actually tried it?